# cg cloud modeler: user authentication failed

Tags: oauth2, authentication, winter24, consumergoodscloud

Consumer Goods Cloud Offline App gets an error: User authentication has failed (Code: U1000)

This happens when trying to connect after being asked to log in.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Do note that we're not an official part of Salesforce. While there are some Salesforce employees among us, most of us are customers of Salesforce and we're all volunteering our time and knowledge. The more information you can provide, the better; but this might be an issue that you should raise a case with [Salesforce's official customer support](https://help.salesforce.com/s/) for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen other users too reporting this error. It appears to be an issue with the Winter'24 release and the Salesforce product team is actively working for a fix.

Please subscribe to the Known issue for updates: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uXUXF/error-logging-into-consumer-goods-offline-app--error-user-authentication-has-failed-code-u1000

You can try below workarounds:

For Modeler Scenario:
In the Browser on the “Clockwork Framework” Tab (Execute As) you need to append the following parameter to the URL and reload the page:
&sfSubDomainURL=https://test.salesforce.com/

For Mobile Device:
Please add the custom domain to the mobility setting under sync management | sync configuration and use the QR code to launch the app. Or, use the custom domain also in the login screen.

Comment: hi @Swetha,

Greetings,

thank you very much for your reply. I think this issue belongs to the Winter'24 update as you say, because I am using the custom domain in the mobile, I still have the same error.

Comment: Known Issue link: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uXUXF/error-logging-into-consumer-goods-offline-app--error-user-authentication-has-failed-code-u1000

Comment: Can you try these steps: 
a. Uninstall the app
b. Make changes to the mobility setting > Custom domain > use .sandbox (Example: abc--uat.sandbox)
generate QR, and importantly save it.
c. reinstall
d. Scan the QR code

Comment: Hi @Swetha Greetings, I have tried to do that step, but there is a restriction when using ---uat.sanbox, it does not accept that kind of format. For the Modeler scenario we do not have this error only on the Mobile Device. We have another environment that still doesn't have the Winter'24 release and the application runs without problem.